# Reactjs onBlur-navbar

Tags: reactjs

This is the initial state before the click.

```
this.state = {
      isNavOpen: false
};
```

And this is the toggler which is working as it should be

```
 toggleNav() {
    this.setState({
      isNavOpen: !this.state.isNavOpen
    });
  }
```

This navbar i want to collapse when its onblur but don't know why i am getting errors.

```
onBlur(e) {
         var currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
         setTimeout(function() {
           if (!currentTarget.contains(document.activeElement)) {
             this.setState({
               isNavOpen: this.state.isNavOpen
             });
           }
         }, 0);
       }
```

This the element i want to toggle on blur when a link is clicked

```
<NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNav} tabIndex="1" onBlur={this.onBlur} />
<Collapse isOpen={this.state.isNavOpen} navbar>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: sazing  isNavOpen not defind

Comment: Within `onBlur` ? Did you bind this method?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read propert 'isNavOpen' of undefined

Comment: this.toggleNav = this.toggleNav.bind(this);
        this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          isNavOpen: false
        };

Comment: But what's with `setTimeout`

Comment: i want to put a timeout so incase nothing is clicked after opening the menu so it will collapse after some seconds say 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ramiz solution which removed the error but blur didn't work so i changed it like this:

```
  onBlur(e) {
       var currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
       setTimeout(function() {
         if (!currentTarget.contains(document.activeElement)) {
           this.setState({
             isNavOpen: !this.state.isNavOpen
           });
         }
       }.bind(this), 0);
    }
```

This "isNavOpen: !this.state.isNavOpen"

Answer (score 1):

According to your error description and your code, it looks like you are missing a `bind` for `setTimeout`. Try that:

```
onBlur(e) {
   var currentTarget = e.currentTarget;
   setTimeout(function() {
     if (!currentTarget.contains(document.activeElement)) {
       this.setState({
         isNavOpen: !this.state.isNavOpen
       });
     }
   }.bind(this), 0);
}
```

Comment: But the `this` you are calling within `setTimeout` is referring to `setTimeout` scope

Comment: within the constructor i also have 
this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);

Comment: yeah, that is necessary to be able to call for example `this.setState` within `onBlur`. Since you are calling it within `setTimeout` you also need to bind it to the component scope.